# Open graph fetching meta data

Tags: java, playframework, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I am using open graph library to fetch the metadata from url.
I am getting the title and description from url link which follow **og tag** rules. How to get metadata from url link which don't follow **og tag**.
my simple code :

```
OpenGraph data = new OpenGraph(url, true);
            response.setDescription(data.getContent("description"));
            response.setMetaDataImage(data.getContent("image"));
            response.setTitle(data.getContent("title"));
            response.setMetaDataUrl(data.getContent("url"));
```

Data fetch is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about [this library](https://github.com/johndeverall/opengraph-java). If so, the boolean in the constructor serves the purpose:

```
public OpenGraph(String url, boolean ignoreSpecErrors) {
    ...
}
```

The way I use this library to fetch, for example, images is as follows:

```
OpenGraph og = new OpenGraph(url, true);
MetaElement[] imageElements = og.getProperties("image");
```

Perhaps you are just using the wrong getter? If the page has og tags, this snippet should work!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with [opengraph-java](https://github.com/johndeverall/opengraph-java) (ie. getting null response).

I tried the example in the docs, but the response was `null`

```
OpenGraph movie = new OpenGraph("http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/back_to_the_future/", true);
System.out.println("movie = " + movie)); // movie = null
```

Trying the `false` option for `ignoreSpecErrors` throws an exception `java.lang.Exception: Does not conform to Open Graph protocol`

So I made a library called [ogmapper](https://github.com/iumehara/ogmapper) that's a little more flexible.

```
DefaultOgMapper ogMapper = new JsoupOgMapperFactory().build();
OgTags ogTags = ogMapper.process(new URL("http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/back_to_the_future/"));
System.out.println("title = " + ogTags.getTitle()); // title = Back to the Future (1985)
```

Hopefully this is helpful!